# Why am I getting a type mismatch error with a type I cannot see anywhere in my solution?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the following error in an editor template of mine, `ApplicantAddressMode`:

> error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'Comair.RI.ViewModels.ApplicantAddressType' and
>   'Comair.RI.Models.ApplicantTypesOfAddress'"}

The type `Comair.RI.ViewModels.ApplicantAddressType` is nowhere to be found. A global solution search of all files for just the `ApplicantAddressType` returns no results. I changed the name of the enum in `Comair.RI.Models` from `ApplicantAddressType` to `ApplicantTypesOfAddress` to try and avoid an unintentional match, and cleaned out both 32 bit and 64 bit Temporary ASP Internet Files, and yet the error still persists on this line of the editor template:

```
@using Comair.RI.Models
@model Comair.RI.ViewModels.ApplicantAddressModel
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>@Model.AddressTypeDescription</legend>
    <ul class="form-column">
        @if (Model.AddressType != ApplicantTypesOfAddress.Residential)
        {
```

`Model.AddressType` is declared as:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public ApplicantTypesOfAddress AddressType { get; set; }
```

I am at my wits end about to start throwing flaming, pointed flags around, like `IsResidentialStreetNumber` and `IsPostalSuburb`. I don't think the ambulances will arrive long after that and take me away to peace.

The enum declaration is like this:

```
namespace Comair.RI.Models
{
    public enum ApplicantTypesOfAddress
    {
        Residential,
        Postal
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you define `ApplicantTypesOfAddress`? Is it just a regular enum?

Comment: Your types look like they span assemblies. Is there a chance of the assembly for `Model` being stale? You mention you cleaned up, but this is the only logical explanation I can think of.

Comment: Would `!Model.AddressType.Equals(ApplicantTypesOfAddress.Residential)` work?

Comment: Yes @Jon, that is all I can think of. This is a relatively small solution and an errant declaration would be very hard to not find.

Comment: @IronMan84 The error just changes to `error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Comair.RI.ViewModels.ApplicantAddressType' and 'Comair.RI.Models.ApplicantTypesOfAddress'"}`

Comment: Can you add the definition for Comair.RI.ViewModels.ApplicantAddressModel ?

Comment: Did you try to Clean solution, restart Visual Studio and Rebuild solution? Does code span multiple projects? If yes, did you make a project or assembly references? Did you place any of the assemblies in Global Assembly Cache?

Comment: This is just hunch. Try decorating the `public ApplicantTypesOfAddress AddressType { get; set; }` property with `[DesignerSerializationVisibilty(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]`. Also make sure that the assembly in which this property and its class are declared is not referencing itself (I know, sounds stupid, but could happen). Also, if you have a RESX file associated with that particular view try opening it and see if you don't have a base64 encoding of a serialization of a former enum's instance (if you do, delete it carefully).

Comment: Any vocationally mature developer should recognize the symptoms of an issue like this, and compiling or not compiling views is definitely not "an extraordinarily narrow" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tpe that was suspected missing was declared in a file not included in the project. When you tell VS to build view at compile time, which in normally only does just before rendering them, not when it builds the application assembly, it builds all views, and uses any files they refer to whether they are included in the project or not.

[Jim Lamb](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/) has a good post on how to do this called [Turn on Compile-time View Checking for ASP.NET MVC Projects in TFS Build 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/04/20/turn-on-compile-time-view-checking-for-asp-net-mvc-projects-in-tfs-build-2010.aspx)

I don't know about the *TFS Build* part though. I don't use that, in my case simply adding the following element to my `.csproj` file did the trick. Note, if the `MvcBuildViews` element already exists, it's text value must be *true.*

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Caveat Emptor.